# Delete column based if value not in array

Tags: excel, vba

I have a financial model that I only want to copy and paste values for 3 worksheets in a new workbook. The model has FY17 to FY28 in row 7 and I only want to keep FY17 to FY21. Any non-blank cell not matching FY17 to FY21, I want to delete the entire column.

The problem is that the code skips columns and I do not know how to use the ".xl last column end" to fix it. I don't think the same logic applies to columns as it does to rows. I only want to delete columns for worksheet1 and worksheet2.

Also, if you could combine the `delete range` sections into one section, that would be great. I tried using the same `array` function as I do copying but apparently, it does not work for deleting?

Thank you.

```
Sub CopyPasteValues()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strSaveName As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim arr
    Dim deleteRange As Range

    'Name of new workbook
    strSaveName = ActiveWorkbook.Name & " VALUES.xlsx"

    'Copy the 3 sheets into new workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("worksheet1", "worksheet2", "worksheet3")).Copy

    'Copy and paste values
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Visible = True Then
            With ws
                .Activate
                .Cells.Copy
                .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
            End With
        End If
    Next ws

    'Deleting column except FY17, FY18, FY19, FY20, FY21

    Set deleteRange = Range("F7:FP7")
    arr = Array("FY17", "FY18", "FY19", "FY20", "FY21")

    For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("worksheet1").Range("F7:FP7")
        If IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, arr, 0)) Then
            cell.EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next

    For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("worksheet2").Range("F7:FP7")
        If IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, arr, 0)) Then
            cell.EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\..." & strSaveName, FileFormat:=51

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Each Loop doesn't work well on this scenario just because you are deleting columns from the collection.

When you delete Col F, your range gets moved towards the left and Col G data will be in Col F. This makes the code unreliable.

Instead of For Each method, the below works based on column number which starts the loop from Col FP to F which is more consistent. Also, I have created an array for the worksheets which again gets looped.

```
 Sub CopyPasteValues()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, objWksht As Worksheet
    Dim strSaveName As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim arr, ShtArr, Shtloop

    'Name of new workbook
    strSaveName = ActiveWorkbook.Name & " VALUES.xlsx"

    'Copy the 3 sheets into new workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("worksheet1", "worksheet2", "worksheet3")).Copy

    'Copy and paste values
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Visible = True Then
            With ws
                .Activate
                .Cells.Copy
                .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
            End With
        End If
    Next ws

    'Deleting column except FY17, FY18, FY19, FY20, FY21

    arr = Array("FY17", "FY18", "FY19", "FY20", "FY21")
    ShtArr = Array("worksheet1", "worksheet2")

    For Shtloop = LBound(ShtArr) To Ubount(ShtArr)
        Set objWksht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ShtArr(Shtloop)) 'loops the worksheet
            '172 Refers to Column FP; 6 refers to Column F
        For ColNumb = 172 To 6 Step -1
            If IsError(Application.Match(objWksht.Cells(7, ColNumb).Value, arr, 0)) Then
                objWksht.Cells(7, ColNumb).EntireColumn.Delete
            End If
        Next ColNumb
    Next Shtloop

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\..." & strSaveName, FileFormat:=51

End Sub
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.